# Bash function not returning the value as expected

Tags: bash

This is a small portion of a larger script, but it doesn't show the right result. I want it to check for a folder, if that folder exists then check for number of files in it. If empty then exit (continue with larger script). Or maybe it should be a large function?
The script:

```
#!/bin/bash
BU_DIR=~/Backups

function Func_CountFiles() {
    FILES=$(find ${BU_DIR} -type f | wc -l )
    # echo $BU_FILES
}

###     Get files from Backupfolder
#
if [ ! -d "${BU_DIR}" ]; then
    BU_Status="Directory, ($BU_DIR), not found!"
    else
        Files=$(Func_CountFiles)
        if [ $Files -le "0" ]; then
            FU_Status="Current dir, ($BU_DIR), is empty."
        else
            # Files=$(Func_CountFiles)
        BU_Status="Current dir, ($BU_DIR), contains $Files."
        fi
fi
exit 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is right, but you are not *returning* anything to the calling function. You need the return the value by printing the variable value `FILES`. Only then the variable `Files` in the calling function is updated with the count you are determining in the `Func_CountFiles()`. Do

```
function Func_CountFiles() {
    fileCount=$(find ${BU_DIR} -type f | wc -l )
    printf "%d" "$fileCount"
}
```

and capture the value of called function as

```
declare -i file_count_from_function 
file_count_from_function=$(Func_CountFiles)
printf "%d\n" "$file_count_from_function"
```

and since you are using `bash` use its own arithmetic operator `((..))` for numeric evaluations. You can use the variables for arithmetic evaluations just as you do in C programming.

```
if (( file_count_from_function <= 0 )); then
```

Comment: Thanx, U made my day. Now it works and I can implement it in the larger script.